# Multiple CADisplayLink animations at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a few buttons which animate a view to make it slide across the screen in different directions though if I press two of the buttons at once the old animation stops and the new one starts and then when I release the newly pressed button the old animation restarts. I was wondering if it were possible to run both animations at once and if so how?

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(void) click {
    if (!self.animating) {
        self.animating = YES;
        timer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(move)];
        [timer setFrameInterval:1];
        [timer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
}

- (void) cancelClick {
    self.animating = NO;
    [timer invalidate];
}

-(void) move {
    CGPoint origin = self.target.frame.origin;
    if ([self.direction isEqual:@"left"]) {
        origin.x -= self.magnitude;
    } else if ([self.direction isEqual:@"right"]) {
        origin.x += _magnitude;
    } else if ([self.direction isEqual:@"up"]) {
        origin.y -= _magnitude;
    } else {
        origin.y += _magnitude;
    }
    [self.target move:0 toPoint:origin animated:NO delay:0 animationOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
}
```

Thanks in advance